# Apache "SSLCipherSuite" Directive

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

[Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslciphersuite) describes the `SSLCipherSuite` directive:

> Cipher Suite available for negotiation in SSL handshake

Let's say I configured this directive to `HIGH` to only use Triple DES encryption.

Would **only** the SSL handshake use Triple DES, or **all** traffic would use this scheme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During the [TLS handshake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_handshake_in_detail), a cipher suite is *agreed* between the peers to be used during the transmission, although ["at any time, due to internal or external stimulus (either automation or user intervention), either side may renegotiate the connection"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Description).

As described in the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslciphersuite) you referenced:

```
An SSL cipher specification in _cipher-spec_ is composed of 4 major attributes plus a few extra minor ones:

- Key Exchange Algorithm: RSA or Diffie-Hellman variants.
- Authentication Algorithm: RSA, Diffie-Hellman, DSS or none.
- Cipher/Encryption Algorithm: DES, Triple-DES, RC4, RC2, IDEA or none.
- MAC Digest Algorithm: MD5, SHA or SHA1.
```

Note that setting `SSLCipherSuite` to `HIGH` does not restrict the list to triple DES. Compare the output of these commands:

```
# openssl ciphers 'HIGH'
# openssl ciphers '3DES'
```

You might want to consider using [AES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554526/comparison-of-des-triple-des-aes-blowfish-encryption-for-data) instead.

The order in which the cipher suite is evaluated is important, security-wise. Check [this](https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2011/10/17/mitigating-the-beast-attack-on-tls) article on BEAST attack mitigation for a detailed explanation. An example from that article:

```
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH
```

A thorough analysis of the protocol can be found in [this](http://www.moserware.com/2009/06/first-few-milliseconds-of-https.html) blog post.

Comment: Glad to be helpful.